# Cannot import views from xml sheet into MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, xml

I've got a bunch of views in my XML sheet that I need to manipulate in my MainActivity.java file.  Here is how I am trying to do this in my MainActivity.java file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

 EditText txt_Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_UserName);
 EditText txt_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_Password);
 Button btn_LogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_LogIn);
 CheckBox chkbox_RememberMyPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_RememberPassword);
 CheckBox chkbox_LogMeInAutomatically = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_LogMeInAutomatically);
 ProgressBar progressbar_LogIn = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_LogIn);

}
```

This does not work, however and when I go to test this code, none of the views are even loaded. I get a blank Activity background and then it crashes.

Am I putting my variable declarations in the right spot?  I'm confused here, I think.

Comment: put the same in onCreate() after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText txt_Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_UserName);
        EditText txt_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_Password);
        Button btn_LogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_LogIn);
        CheckBox chkbox_RememberMyPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_RememberPassword);
        CheckBox chkbox_LogMeInAutomatically = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_LogMeInAutomatically);
        ProgressBar progressbar_LogIn = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_LogIn);
    }
}
```

You had your variable initialization outside of a method block, which means that it will be run before any method of your Activity. Since `findViewById()` looks for Views in the currently inflates layout, your app would crash with a `NullPointerException` as there is no currently inflated layout. Your layout is only inflated after `setContentView()` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     EditText txt_Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_UserName);
     EditText txt_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_Password);
     Button btn_LogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_LogIn);
     CheckBox chkbox_RememberMyPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_RememberPassword);
     CheckBox chkbox_LogMeInAutomatically = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_LogMeInAutomatically);
     ProgressBar progressbar_LogIn = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_LogIn);

    }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code

```
 EditText txt_Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_UserName);
 EditText txt_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_Password);
 Button btn_LogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_LogIn);
 CheckBox chkbox_RememberMyPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_RememberPassword);
 CheckBox chkbox_LogMeInAutomatically = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_LogMeInAutomatically);
 ProgressBar progressbar_LogIn = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_LogIn);``
```

Inside

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //Put the above block of code here

}
```

In android app Activity handels the UI .So inside `onCreate` of an activity you are setting UI layout

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

The you are initializing the components in your UI

Extras : If you are beginner .Read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) and [refer](http://manisivapuram.blogspot.in/2011/07/activity-life-cycle-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

put all your view into onCreate() but after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main).
It is mean create all the view when application is created.